# Is it easy to remove encryption's password prompt on boot if I don't want it anymore?

Tags: 5.0-lollipop, security, encryption

As discussed [here](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/180949/why-encrypt-the-device), there are some notable benefits to phone encryption, so I'm about to try it for the first time. Before doing it:

1. will I be able to remove the password / lock in the future, after encryption? or will it to be mandatory to have to enter a password on phone boot? I.e. if I don't want any protection anymore, will there always be a password prompt on boot or can I disable this? (btw: I read that totally disabling encryption needs a full format / factory reset)
2. have you noticed a lower performance after encryption, on everyday use (browsing, basic apps, etc.)?

I have a Samsung a3 2015 with android 5.0.2.

Answer (score 0):

It's not quite easy, but rather complicated to remove encryption depending on how much data you have on your phone.

Removing encryption, AFAIK, requires **formatting `/data` partition**. So all you have to do is

- Copy out all personal files from internal storage (assume you have a shared storage)
- Make a backup, if you want to continue using the phone ASAP
- **Format `/data`**
- Copy everything back
- Restore from backup

The encryption removal itself is, rather fast (a few seconds). The only complication is backup & restore.

Performance issues:

The encryption is done at real-time, so whenever an app wants to read or write data, enc/dec is done before reading from/after writing to disk. This, however, does not have a great impact on CPU. I haven't noticed a great performance degradation with encryption (with my OnePlus 5), so I believe it's safe to have encryption enabled without worrying about performance issues **on modern phones**. It has always been complained about by Nexus 6 users. You'd better stay away from it if you're using a phone with eMMC storage and a non-flagship SoC.

Comment: Thanks. I meant: is it possible to remove the boot password prompt even if encryption is enable? ie encryption is still on, but we don't care about it and remove the boot password  prompt. is that possible?

Comment: can I keep the encryption on, but disable the password prompt on boot @iBug?

Comment: @Basj I don't have a startup password with my phone. I only have a lockscreen.